# How to query LOB field in Oracle using R

Tags: r, oracle, oracle11g, dbi, roracle

How can I query a LOB field from Oracle using ROracle library?

```
library(ROracle)
drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
connect.string <- paste(
  "(DESCRIPTION=",
  "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=", host, ")(PORT=", PORT, "))",
  "(CONNECT_DATA=(GLOBAL_NAME=",GLOBAL_NAME,")(SID=", SID, ")))", sep = "")
con <- ROracle::dbConnect(drv, username = username, password = password, dbname = connect.string)
```

I am a newbie and tried this:

```
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(CAST(LOB_FIELD AS RAW)) FROM TABLEDATA WHERE OTHER_FIELD = 'something'") 

data <- ROracle::fetch(rs)
# Error in .oci.SendQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
  ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis


rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT dbms_lob.READ(LOB_FIELD) FROM TABLEDATA WHERE OTHER_FIELD = 'something'") 

data <- ROracle::fetch(rs)
#Error in .oci.SendQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
  ORA-00904: "DBMS_LOB"."READ": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple with the query

```
select LOB_FIELD from tab where OTHER_FIELD = 'something
```

where `LOB_FILED` is the `CLOB` column

```
df <-   dbGetQuery(conn, "select LOB_FIELD from tab where OTHER_FIELD = 'something'")
nchar(df$LOB_FIELD)
[1] 68000
```

Comment: hi @Marmite Bomber, thanks for your suggestion, I tried `dbGetQuery` and it gave me: `Error in .oci.GetQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
  Error in try({ : 
  embedded nul in string: '{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1033{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Arial;}{\\f1\\fswiss\\fcharset0 JLKEVY+Arial-BoldItalicMT;}}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\i\\fs14\\par\r\n\\par\r\n\\par\r\n\\par\r\n\\par\r\n\\par\r\n\\b\\f1 TEXT \\b0\\f0\\par\r\n}\r\n\0'`